# Antd Design's Form.Item's valuePropName="checked" isn't allowing child checkbox to have property checked={true}

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd design 4 for my react application. I have a checkbox like this:-

```
<Form.Item name="is_expirable" label="Is the promo code expirable in nature?" valuePropName="checked">
    <Checkbox onChange={onIsExpirableChange}>Yes</Checkbox>
</Form.Item>
```

Now I am trying to add checked property to the checkbox, something like this:-

```
<Form.Item name="is_expirable" label="Is the promo code expirable in nature?" valuePropName="checked">
    <Checkbox checked={promoCodeIsExpirable} onChange={onIsExpirableChange}>Yes</Checkbox>
</Form.Item>
```

So that the checkbox will be displayed as checked during the load time. But the property `valuePropName="checked"` is causing weird activities.

1. If I am adding `valuePropName="checked"` in the checkbox, the checkbox is displayed as unchecked (though it should be displayed as checked).
2. When I am removing the `valuePropName="checked"`, the checkbox is displayed as checked

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, when wrapping inside a `Form.Item`, the checked/unchecked is handled by the Form (specially since you have set `name`).

So either I would use `initialValues`:

```js
<Form initialValues={{ is_expirable: promoCodeIsExpirable }}>
  <Form.Item name="is_expirable" label="Is the promo code expirable in nature?" valuePropName="checked">
    <Checkbox onChange={onIsExpirableChange}>
      Yes
    </Checkbox>
  </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

Or remove the `Form.Item`.

p.s. if what you need is the layout of Form.Item, then remove the `name` attribute.

Comment: I have kept the Form.Item because by using the valueNameProp, I am validating another input field when the checkbox is checked.